# I have added a mobile number to my developer story profile — who can see that?

Tags: support, developer-story, personal-data

I just updated my developer story with my mobile number, but it's not available from my friend's account also.

What is the privilege to see that information?

Comment: When you say "just" is this a caching issue?

Comment: I believe that you have added the phone number under the Job Match Preferences. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Zanon ya you are rt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338573/sensitive-info-disclosure):

> The phone number is listed under your Job Match preferences and would
>   be used as a way employers could contact you if you’re expressed
>   interest in being contacted or when you’ve applied for a job. Should
>   you want to change or remove the phone number from your profile, that
>   is where it is located.
>
> The only place the phone should ever been seen is to you as the user
>   in your settings, to employers who you expressed interest in or
>   applied to a job for, or on the PDF view of your Developer Story.