# Stack Overflow Jobs - Change Contact Number

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, cv-export

Previously on Stack Overflow Careers I setup a contact number. This number cannot be seen now from the Developer Story view but when ever I generate a PDF it is included.

I have now moved to the US and would like to update my contact number for my CV or alternatively remove it all together. I have gone through the various screens to see if I can edit it but cannot find any reference to it.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338583/2607247) by Bluefeet: _"The phone number is listed under your Job Match preferences and would be used as a way employers could contact you if you’re expressed interest in being contacted or when you’ve applied for a job. Should you want to change or remove the phone number from your profile, that is where it is located."_

Comment: @Kendra - Thanks I'll delete this question

Comment: You don't have to delete it- It can be a good pointer to the information if it's marked as a duplicate. (I'm not too sure about calling it a duplicate myself, or I'd have flagged.) Other people are going to look for this information too, I'm sure.

Comment: @Kendra - If you answer it, with what you put in your comment I can flag it as correct. As you suggested this is not a direct duplicate and the other question may not get picked up by someone else's search.