# A Post-Mortem on the Recent Developer Story Information Leak

Tags: discussion, developer-story, personal-data

> *We'd first like to take a moment to thank everyone for their patience while we put this together. Your restraint was a very big help in us handling this incident with the degree of diligence that all of you deserve; thank you for waiting so patiently as we worked to resolve it.*

#### tl;dr:

On 2016-11-28 it was [brought to our attention](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338573/sensitive-info-disclosure) that we were unintentionally exposing email addresses and phone numbers of users that filled out a Developer Story. The information wasn't actually printed to browsers, but was present in the page's HTML source markup. The bug causing this existed since the Developer Story private beta, but was actually exposed once the beta period switched to public on 2016-10-11.

The bug was immediately fixed, and we spent quite a bit of time working with all major search engines and archival services in order to ensure that the accidentally disclosed information was either suppressed in results pending reindexing, or purged subsequent to reindexing.

This bug affected a very small percentage of Stack Overflow users, limited specifically to users that had filled out a Developer Story prior to 2016-11-28. Discovery of the information was possible only through very specific searches containing the user's email address (if known) or phone number (if known).

***We strongly believe that any potential for inconvenience due to this bug has been mitigated, and that there's no additional cause for concern regarding any accidental disclosure of email addresses or phone numbers. We sincerely apologize if anyone was inconvenienced in any way as we corrected the bug and worked to mitigate any potential lingering effects.***

---

Now, the longer version.

#### What happened, and when?

On 2016-11-28 at approximately 10:30 UTC-0, a user [reported](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338573/sensitive-info-disclosure) that search results for their phone number showed their Stack Overflow Jobs public CV as the first response. Upon examination, we realized that user’s email addresses and telephone numbers were accidentally disclosed within HTML markup that renders the CV page. Neither email addresses or phone numbers were actually rendered, but the HTML code that forms the page contained this information.

The bug was introduced when the Developer Story CV view was checked into our codebase. It was there on 10/11, but also present during the private beta, however the view wasn't yet accessible to crawlers until the public beta.

#### How did this happen?

While porting some of our legacy Careers 2.0 code over to the new integrated Stack Overflow Jobs platform, a view that was originally programmed to render a PDF copy of a user’s CV was reused to render an HTML version of the CV. As the goal was to create a view that rendered similarly as the PDF version, this seemed to be an ideal choice.

A bug that caused the user’s phone number and email address to render in the HTML source for people that weren’t the user or an employer attempting to contact the user went unnoticed, because the information wasn’t actually rendered on the page. The information was only included as part of the source of the page.

#### What did we do?

Once alerted to the bug, we immediately corrected the bug. Our second priority was to get in touch with major search engines in order to get the accidentally disclosed information out of their indexes.

We also notified the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) of the accidental disclosure, who obliged our request to suppress any archived URLs up to the date that the bug was corrected that could contain this information in the HTML source.

#### What is the impact of the disclosure?

We believe that the impact of this disclosure is minimal in the context of any harm or inconvenience for users affected by the bug.

All major search engines have either suppressed this info in results, or re-crawled us at our request thus purging the information from indexes. (Many elected to simply re-index prior to the usual 120 day interval.)

#### Is there anything I need to do?

No. While the information disclosed is personally-identifiable, it was:

- Not actually printed to the screen, it was only visible in the HTML source of the CV page.
- Not easily correlatable; you need to already know a phone number or email address in order to turn it up.

We don't anticipate any lingering impact or potential inconvenience for any users that were affected. If you have additional concerns, please [contact us](//meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) privately and we'll be happy to discuss them.

#### What did we learn from this, and how are we doing things differently?

Personally-identifiable information (PII) is something that every developer needs to handle with care. Fortunately, recognizing PII when you see it isn't all that difficult; if information you're handling can be used to [identify, contact, or locate a single person, or to identify an individual in context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information), it needs to be treated with care.

That's great when you're building new things, but extremely mature code bases have dark and dusty corners where light doesn't often shine. It's extremely important, if not critical, to know when you're working with something that in any way transmits personally-identifiable information in any way.

We've implemented (and recommend others implement) the following scheme to make sure something like this can't happen again:

- Regular code audits to identify any places where PII is stored and / or transmitted, and regular review of the necessity of each instance found. If there's a chunk of code that shows you your email address on a route that's no longer used after other changes, get rid of it.
- Identification of PII in the code base and database, so developers immediately know if the code they're working with stores or transmits PII and precisely the kind of information that needs to be considered.
- Ensuring that the definition of personally-identifiable information is disambiguated entirely, so that there's no question or subjective interpretation of what should be treated differently at all.

I'd like to reiterate, ***we believe you don't have anything to worry about, and this bug only potentially impacted those that filled out a Developer Story between 2016-10-11 and 2016-11-28***. And, again, the surface to take advantage of this bug was quite small, and required prior knowledge of the information that was accidentally disclosed.

But we take our responsibility as custodians of your information and trust very seriously; now that we've taken every possible measure to mitigate any potential inconvenience to those affected, we feel that we owe it to you to be as transparent about what happened as possible.

If you have any additional concerns, please [contact us](//meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) privately to discuss them.

Comment: *"this bug only potentially impacted those that filled out a Developer Story between 2016-10-11 and 2016-11-28"* Just to clarify, did we have to explicitly add this information to a "Developer Story", or was our existing information from the Careers site automatically migrated into a "Developer Story"? If I remember correctly, there was some kind of automatic migration done of the information you already had from me.

Comment: It took *exactly* [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) to fix it...

Comment: @CodyGray Migrated users were also affected, but the vast majority of them had their stories set to private upon migration, so there wasn't a public link in which this bug would have affected them. It really is confined to folks that actively tinkered with / updated their Dev stories and made them public.

Comment: Although I see the concept of "no huge harm done", aren't you planning to make this post featured?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't see the harm in adding it, though this will shortly be on the 'hot on meta' list which is essentially the same thing. I just have to remember to remove the tag on Friday so I'm not blocking a spot for a more major (e.g. docs or something else) functionality update.

Comment: `Discovery of the information was possible only through very specific searches` -> Well, a crafty person could have simply clicked "view page source" and noticed the information was there. Who knows if it was extracted from all the published developer stories by a bot? There is no practical way of knowing if someone did, but it's entirely feasible given that the recruiting industry seems to have plenty of actors with a rather flexible sense of ethics, relatively high value of the information, and past efforts of scraping this sort of information from SO.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That's one of the first things we thought, too. We took a look at our load balancer / access logs as we were fixing the bug, and from what we could tell, it was only the normal symphony of crawlers. We of course can't be 100% certain but it doesn't look like that scenario happened. Could a shady recruiter have updated their user scripts after the bug was reported publicly? _Possibly_, but it was fixed really quickly - I'm doubtful.

Comment: Double points for going the extra mile then. Strange you didn't mention that in the pos
t mortem though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I consolidated a whole lot of stuff into that, a lot of people did a lot of quick thinking on their feet. Just an oversight (and, for brevity sake, that was already getting longer than I hoped) :)

Comment: I don't think it's plausible that this was abused after the bug was found. But I could imagine that someone looks at the source to see if they can gain any additional info, and if they bump into an e-mail address, they start poking around in a targeted way. Obviously they wouldn't inform SO about this, they'll just silently keep crawling the pages. (I'm not saying that this happened, or that it's likely or not; but this scenario seems more likely to me than the exploit after day 0.)

Comment: If this exposure significantly increases shady parties' access to your PII, you're doing awfully well...

Comment: I'm not really concerned about this since my email address is all over the Internet anyway and easily correlated. My phone number wasn't provided.

Comment: Excellent transparency and increases faith in the brand!

Comment: Perhaps the people coding the site didn't know enough about pointers and recursion?

Comment: Thanks for the post mortem. That said, if I understand what happened, "_you need to already know a phone number or email address in order to turn it up_" is not correct. One could have retrieved the phone number from the page source, so the only information required to get the phone number was the name of the person.

Comment: One question that might be worth discussion is whether the original meta post raising this bug should have been temporarily deleted or somehow hidden. It sounds like the overall handling of the issue was great, but the chance of some recruiter manually going and grabbing info from candidates in the meantime (as Carpetsmoker suggests) must have been hugely increased by that meta post

Comment: @ken2k I assume that means something like "there's so much HTML source, you'd have to ctrl-f the email to find the phone number, or vice-versa", which doesn't sound very reassuring.

Comment: @Ben raises a fair point there... perhaps reports of security flaws like this  should be temporarily deleted as a policy (of course informing both the author, and any 10k+ users looking at it) once it is recognized the issue is real, and undeleted once it is resolved

Comment: @Pekka웃 Whether it's actually a good idea I have no opinion, but it seems like something that should at least get discussed (if it hasn't already)

Comment: @Pekka웃 that could be an option, but you have to balance that with the transparency aspect too.  Temporarily deleting a post exposing a security flaw could be seen as trying to hide the flaw from the user community, even if the intention is nobel

Comment: @TimPost _This bug affected a very small percentage of Stack Overflow users, limited specifically to users that had filled out a Developer Story prior to 2016-11-28. Discovery of the information was possible only through very specific searches containing the user's email address (if known) or phone number (if known)_ this is incorrect. The information was exposed to anybody visiting a developer story page, and someone who knew about it could have found this info from everyone they knew the name of.

Comment: @BenAaronson at least in this specific case, only 2 hours passed between posting the bug and fixing it. Of course your concerns are valid from a general, policy forming aspect.

Comment: @BenAaronson When the bug was first reported, there was [some discussion even by some users about whether the report should be deleted](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5459739#5459739). We discussed it internally as well, but it was already out there getting attention on MSO and we didn't want it to appear that we were hiding it. The team frantically worked to fix the bug to minimize any impact.

Comment: Oh, come on. I can't believe someone took the suggestion in my first comment seriously.

Comment: @Glorfindel There's always one

Comment: Actually, there are four now.

Comment: @Glorfindel I propose a 5 minute suspension for the close voters!

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm almost tempted to add the final close vote myself so I can see who voted to close this ...

Comment: Besides of privacy is first priority, it seems a bit controversial to worry about some "unethical recruiter bot attack" discovery, because (you admit or not) one of the main reason of _publishing_ anything about your professional life/skills is to attract potential future recruiters/employers and advertise what a cool guy are you. Worry about instead internet criminals who may try act on behalf of you if they got your personal information.

Comment: @g.pickardou I think folks worry about it mostly in the context of not wanting to be bothered by junk calls / emails. It's much more of a potential inconvenience than it is a threat. To this day,  I still get calls on my mobile by people that think I'm a flash developer :/

Comment: @bluefeet IMO that was the right call, but I wonder if it might be worth having an explicit policy on this for next time. You could even make a new question/announcement replacing the hidden one which explains that a question was removed, why, roughly what it covered (without potentially harmful details), and saying that it will be unhidden once the issue is dealt with. I think if there was a policy like that, publicly agreed on in advance, for specific cases like this, most people would see that as sufficiently transparent.

Comment: @BenAaronson, I agree 1000%. I see nothing wrong with an acknowledgment with a statement indicative of the event and process underway to mitigate. I can almost guarantee that as the OP was being read some readers where testing the function to confirm the post. Hopefully, although they may have tested/confirmed/observed the details, morality kicked in and nothing was recorded. More likely though any reader in the earliest observation of the post didn't have any motivation to use the information.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker check the timeline.

Comment: This is exactly why (iirc) I never entered my phone number. And here I thought that because I was paranoid, they probably weren't after me. [Kurt](http://www.burntout.com/songs/lyrics/nevermind.html) (et al) was (were) right. Seriously, though, if SE/SO screws this up, well... Hope there's something in the system now that logs any access of [PII-related fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) in the database(s), and that it's reviewed regularly. 

Comment: @TimPost just a reminder so that you don't forget to un-feature this post;) Thanks for making it featured in the first place.

Comment: This post is missing an important detail: how do I find out whether I have provided a phone number and email or not? I couldn't even find a place where I could enter this.

Comment: @Thomas: On the main site, goto "Edit Profile and Settings".  The last item on the "Job Match Preferences" subpage is phone number.

Comment: My phone # was exposed all this time and no one called me. Not even a single recruiter cold call. :( Considering legal action against SE for false advertising

Comment: *Oh, come on. I can't believe someone took the suggestion in my first comment seriously.* <-- and it's happening now **again**.

Comment: Well I am happy to know that even SO is human and makes bugs like the rest of us :-)

Comment: @SList but what happens if the SO developers make a mistake and SO goes down and they need help. If that happens, the world is doomed because they can't use SO to ask for help. D:

Comment: @TimPost Could it be, that somebody used some crafty "searchengine-hacks" to lookup the crawlers' data from that period, and get the phone numbers / emails by some more creative means, like making the search engine show the info inside the search results (even if the info is only visible in the source code of the page)? I have a memory of a similar hack from somewhere, and it would completely bypass your logs.

Comment: @TimPost Also, have you contacted these guys? https://nerdydata.com/search

Comment: @Glorfindel Probably being trolled by the hundreds of people who upvote helpful and very interesting questions which later get closed by a tiny number of individuals for whatever unhelpful reason they can dream up. Just one of the many flaws on this site which will never be fixed. And if it's not trolling, it's just yet another case of close powers being abused.

Comment: @Manius [**attempt 3**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/13077). No close *vote* to be seen this time, just a flag I guess.

Comment: I think that manual code audits are good but insufficient. Anything that is served to the public should be string-searched for leaks against a fake honeypot account's personally identifiable data.

Comment: I say "free t-shirts for everyone!"

Comment: @KubaOber Fake honeypot accounts are a great way of finding leaks, at the very least after they have been lost.

Comment: @KubaOber: That's merely automating a weak approach. A much stronger guarantee can be had by securing sensitive data. File systems/operating systems have been doing this for decades, successfully. From what I understand, the SE team has not implemented, or considered implementing a system to enforce security, such that certain privileges are required to access sensitive data.

Comment: A 'Post Mortem' :) . This is exactly Why we Love stackoverflow

Comment: @IInspectable The goal is for the sensitive data not to leak. I am completely baffled how any tool that gives a decent yes/no answer to the question of "does my code leak sensitive data" would be considered weak. Of course you should strive to have leak-freedom by design, but design is merely a fancy term for stuff in human brains - stuff that does go wrong on occasion. A tool looking for leaks is a good ally.

Comment: @KubaOber: That tool requires 100% test coverage to be reliable. Good luck. (This should be obvious, but here it goes anyway: Being lucky is not a scalable or reliable solution to securing data.)

Comment: @IInspectable All that the tool needs to do is usefully reduce the probability that a bug will slip. The only things that are 100% are machine-processable proofs. Everything else is us being lucky to an extent.

Comment: @KubaOber: I would hope that organizations that store PII (or any sort of sensitive data) don't subscribe to the idea, that it's enough to *"usefully reduce the probability \[to leak that information\]"*. Actually, I'm not sure here anymore, and have to ask: Are you serious?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm serious. I don't know what, uh, alternatives do you propose to *usefully reducing the probability of a leak*. The only alternative that we *know* makes leaks impossible is to use a fully certified toolset, hardware, OS and software where there are mathematical proofs of correctness. We know enough to pull that off, but that's about the only case where you can say "here's the proof it'll not leak, as long as the transistors work the way we want them to and people don't fail". Everything else is merely reducing the probability of a leak.

Comment: @KubaOber: Just to clarify: Would you classify operating system security as a means to *"reduce the probability to leak sensitive data"*, too? If that is the case, then you are unduly representing your hypothetical tool to look way more reliable than it can be made.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I am. Because it's as simple of a human mistake to misconfigure things to leak because file access rights are wrong in the OS as it is the way it's described in this post-mortem. OS-based security reduces the likelihood of certain bugs leaking, but that's a conditional reduction, not an absolute one. All the little things we do aim to reduce the likelihood of stuff going wrong. Having a regression test (the simple tool I propose is nothing more) is IMHO the least one could do. If for nothing else than to support test-driven development as a sensible means of staying sane.

Comment: IOW, as this post-mortem demonstrates, having very thick shields (e.g. an intricate selinux setup) doesn't help much if you aren't any less likely to run into a problem that is a neutrino and laughs at you as it passes you by. Regression tests are by definition 100% good at catching their designated neutrinos, at least. Cast a wide enough net and such a simple approach can do better than Nature here :)

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm afraid, I cannot agree with any of that. A regression test can only find defects it was specifically implemented to find. System-level enforced access control can prevent **any** attempt to move high-integrity data to low-integrity clients. By design. That's a world of a difference, hence you haven't succeeded in rebutting my previous assessment: Regression testing is a great improvement to a weak tool, when it comes to securing data.

Comment: _"The information wasn't actually printed to browsers, but was present in the page's HTML source markup."_ ? How can both portions of the sentence, before and following comma, be equally true at the same time?

Comment: @TimPost Can you clearly define the term "printed", as applied, within the text of Question?

Comment: Moderators, staff. Not sure why comments evaluating the actual text of Question were deleted? The first portion of referenced sentence is either a hedge; a technical or pseudo legal term of art, intended maintain the avenue of plausible deniability, or deliberate misinformation. The sentence defies logic. The fact that persons were aware of the issue, and evidently considered the text of the Question, well, before posting is revealing. Delete the excuses or attempts to confuse users with terms, as applied, including, but not limited to "printed" left wholly undefined. Just tell the truth.

Comment: Disclosing this is a big plus; I really appreciate it. On the other hand, as a developer who works on projects that access PII/FTI daily, I'm a little shaken the sensitivity of PII wasn't known or taken with extreme care prior to this event. Granted, I may hold SO to a higher standard than the average website.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/126CZqbY33wNgc/giphy.gif

Comment: "we believe you don't have anything to worry about, and this bug only potentially impacted those that filled out a Developer Story between 2016-10-11 and 2016-11-28" That's a nice platitude. By the way the maximum fine from the UK's ICO for breaches of the Data Protection Act is £500,000. Note that a fine needn't be dependent on the data actually being used by someone else, merely disclosure.

Comment: The question has two close votes now, but I don't see any close votes in the Review queue. Where do I go to click "Leave open"? Also, I didn't know people could vote to close a question and then later vote to reopen.

Comment: I don't totally understand the nuances from the explanation.  Isn't it the case that since the various search engines were indexing and finding and showing in search results the personal information, that information would have been easily and clearly visible to people searching between date X and Y on search engines A, B, C, D, E, etc?  In other words, on the site the info was invisible, in the source the info was visible, and on search engines between these two dates the info was trivially available to end user searches?

Comment: Have you looked at your server log referrer URLs to determine how many times a Developer Story page was retrieved based on a phone number or email search?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: FWIW, I would be careful not to equate "taking the sensitivity of PII with extreme care" with actually being 100% secure with zero leaks. You can take all the care and implement all the measures in the world but mistakes and oversights can (and sometimes do) happen. No one has written a 100% bug-free program of this level of complexity.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Presumably, *far more* care was taken here, even prior to the bug being exposed on meta, than when [someone uploaded a photo of their screen with usernames and passwords onto their Stack Overflow question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341336/rollback-edit-which-inlined-very-low-quality-image).

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm not equating taking care with being perfect. When SO voluntarily accepts users' private information they take on an additional responsibility that needs oversight and processes to ensure the information remains private. I would be careful not to equate a bug that exposes this information to any old bug. I'm lost on the point of the last comment. I'm sure they did put more than *zero* effort at keeping the data safe; so what?

Answer (score 140):

### Frequently Asked Questions

***What telephone number was leaked?***

The telephone number listed under your Job Match preferences, which was expected to be only used as a way for employers to contact you if you have expressed interest in being contacted or when you’ve applied for a job.

***What email address was leaked?***

The email address you provided for employers to contact you.

***Did this affect me if my Developer Story was private?***

No. If your developer story was set to private, the information was not exposed.

***Did this affect me if my Careers profile was migrated into a Developer Story?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***How many users were affected?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***Were [archive services other than the WayBack Machine](https://www.quora.com/Aside-from-the-Wayback-Machine-what-are-other-options-for-getting-screenshots-of-websites-from-the-past) notified?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***Does Stack Overflow have an established policy for responding to unauthorized disclosure of user private data?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***Was the policy followed in this specific instance?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***Will I be notified if my account was individually affected?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***Have you informed the relevant data protection offices in the countries in which StackOverflow operates?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***What policies and procedures are in place to ensure the privacy of user's data during development and in general?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

***I'm not sure when I filled out my developer story. How can I tell if my account was affected?***

*[Awaiting answer]*

Comment: Users: please add common questions which don't need to be discussed privately. Staff: please fill the blanks.

Comment: Good idea, I'll keep an eye on this. Having a single post with questions that don't directly relate to _specific_ information (which we'd need to discuss privately) helps make sure folks see these all in one place. Thanks for the initiative here!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133107/discussion-on-answer-by-oriol-a-post-mortem-on-the-recent-developer-story-inform).

Comment: @BradLarson Is the team looking at answering these?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse - I'm just a moderator, I don't know anything more than you do about these.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Just got back to Manila from NYC (which was almost 24 hours of traveling), I'll try my best to get these filled in this week. Not an oversight, just really crunched on time (and we've got a toddler that's still on EST :/)

Comment: @TimPost If your toddler can stick to a timezone that sounds like progress from what I hear :) Thanks for responding.

Comment: @TimPost - It looks like you never got around to answering these.  Surely there's some answers to these questions after 8 months... :)

Answer (score 57):

> While the information disclosed is personally-identifiable, it was:
>
> **Not actually printed to the screen, it was only visible in the HTML source of the CV page.**
>
> **Not easily correlatable; you need to already know a phone number or email address in order to turn it up.**

The post could do without these weasel words. Personal information was served up and transmitted to clients. Period. The fact that "it was only in the source" makes little difference - as evidenced by the fact that it was indexed by Google, saved by archive.org, and available to anybody who bothered to look. *Maybe* this would fly elsewhere, but it's pretty ridiculous and insulting to our intelligence to try it here where the audience is specifically professional software developers.

Comment: Did you bother to read the whole text? They ensured it's no longer indexed by search engines and that it's no longer available on the Internet Archive. Newsflash: bugs happen, and sometimes they have grave consequences.

Comment: Yes, I read the whole thing. My issue isn't with the fact of the bug occurring but with the wording of the report. I've edited the post to try to make this more clear.

Comment: With all due respect, the issue was solved.  Likewise, this did mean that other than through searching, the average user couldn't find the info.  They made no attempt to cover up the fact that search engines could indeed index the information.  As a Web developer myself, I don't believe that this is an insult to the intelligence of anyone.

Comment: @LeoWilson: The fact is that the last quoted sentence is a blatant lie, you wouldn't need to search based on prior knowledge of the phone number, any search that accesses that Developer Story page would lead to downloading the phone number. (mutatis mutandi for email-address) Furthermore, it is almost certain that some recruiters still have some developer story content stored in browser cache, and can now extract the personal contact information from those.  I'm sorry for you that you don't recognize the whitewash.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, so a hacker who knows HTML and who knew about this glitch, or just so happened to be looking through the code, got your information.  How many people did that?  They were talking about the _average user_.  I don't take information breeches lightly, but let's be honest, this really isn't the worst that could have happened.  Plus, there are much more efficient ways for advanced spammers to get people's personal information.  If you want to quit the site, that's your right in most Western democracies, but seriously, they made _one_ mistake.  Cut them some slack.

Comment: @LeoWilson: What actually happened isn't that bad (the information leaked is generally publicly listed in various directories) so they shouldn't need to try to whitewash it.  And if it isn't a conspiracy to mislead users, that's actually worse, because it means the people responsible for the system don't understand how websites work, which would make me question whether they did after all manage to fix it completely.

Comment: @LeoWilson: They made *two* mistakes: Implementing a bug and misrepresenting its effects. This answer is commenting on the latter, and there is little reason to disagree. One does not need **any** prior knowledge to gain access to the leaked information, and correlate user name, real name, phone number, and email address. This is evidenced by the fact, that PII did show up in search indexes of search engines, that weren't specifically implemented to exploit this bug.

Comment: A while back Stack Overflow changed their Terms of Service in an effort to stop recruiters (or if you're a cynic, Jobs competitors) from scraping this kind of information.  That means at least some people were looking at the source of these pages to write scrapers, and I'd expect at least some of them noticed.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I read through the posting, I had exactly the same thought when I hit the spot with the wrong statement. The fact that the comments tried to pamper over the fact that the statement was wrong made it worse, as it was clearly wrong, and the author knew it to be wrong. This was probably handled well, but not described in a trustworthy way.

Comment: The two points taken together are relevant. What there is a data leak, how likely that leak is to have been noticed and exploited _is_ relevant. The fact it was only buried in source means nobody would spot it by eye, only by crawling. The fact you had to know what to search for is another. These are clearly not posted as excuses but for information to educate you the severity of the breach

Comment: @Mr.Boy: This is incorrect. You didn't have to notice the leak to exploit it. And you didn't have to know what to look for either. Unless you have more information than we do, there is no indication that search engines were specifically trained to exploit this leak. They were just doing business as usual. In other words: The information was there for everyone to pick up, knowingly or by chance. This is the true scope of the leak, and the Post Mortem made no attempt to document it as such.

Comment: I expect a very crude email harvesting bot will download webpages, search for an @ symbol anywhere in the markup, parse the text surrounding the @ to see if its an email address, save any valid email addresses to a database and then follow any links on the page and repeat. These bots will already be out there crawling the web and don't require any specific knowledge of stack overflow or this particular issue that occurred. For that reason I agree its a bit disingenuous to imply that no harm would have been done unless a human was specifically looking at the pagesource

Comment: @LeoWilson "so a hacker who knows HTML" huh?  There is no hacking involved.  View Source is a feature that has been built into web browsers for over a decade (Can't recall if Navigator had the feature).

Comment: The first of the two statements is perfectly reasonable, the second somewhat dubious. On balance though, these guys are doing an awesome job of transparency, and the leak wasn't that bad.

Comment: Seeing as this is a pretty technical site full of pretty technical people, I don't think defining the exact scope and vulnerability of the problem is "weasely". Describing a situation like this shouldn't just be "We leaked your information, sorry." I guarantee if they had described it that way, people would be asking if it was visible, which pages it was on, how easy it would be to find, and so on. They admitted the data was indexed/archived, they aren't trying to hide anything. I read this as a report of the exact facts; "Not actually visible on the screen" is just another important fact.

Answer (score 57):

> We sincerely apologize **if anyone was inconvenienced in any way** as we corrected the bug and worked to mitigate any potential lingering effects.

What I hoped to read at this point is a text like:

> We sincerely apologize **for our failure to keep your personal data confidential**.
>
> We have now corrected the mistake and are undoing its effects to the best of our abilities.

Comment: There's always a critic. Imo the team handled this bug as good as they could possibly have.

Comment: Personally, I do not care about any inconvenience that occurred while they corrected the bug. I do care about sensitive data being exposed unintentionally, and without my permission. The wording of the post above suggests to me that the team is unaware of what the main cause of concern is in this case: Exposing user data. Not inconvenience. The sentence "Discovery of the information was possible only through very specific searches containing the user's email address (if known) or phone number (if known)." casts additional doubt on the team's ability to accurately assess and correct the issue.

Comment: Mat, saying _"our failure to keep your personal data confidential."_ is a perfect guarantee to make readers panic. That's all they see, then. In the end, what matters is that this issue was handled properly. Let's not nitpick about something as trivial as how they worded the post-mortem. SE is damn well aware how important privacy is, but they didn't _have_ to write this wall of text. They came out and fessed up, full transparency. Let's give them the benefit of the doubt (That is, if you have any reason to doubt their intentions)

Comment: That's *not at all* what I regard "full transparency". Consider for example the following suggestion: "In the time period between date X and date Y, the following information was publicly accessible in the source code of the following subset of Stackoverflow pages (...) The information appeared in the source code and was indexed by major search engines as well as the Internet Archive. The attributes were not displayed when the pages were rendered on screen." The potential of users panicking should not prevent telling the truth. That's also not "nitpicking", but suggesting how to build trust.

Comment: What about the post suggests SO is trying to hide the indexing? _"we spent quite a bit of time working with all major search engines and archival services in order to ensure that the accidentally disclosed information was either suppressed in results pending reindexing, or purged subsequent to reindexing."_ They're well aware it was indexed and they've put significant effort into getting it removed.They're not "not telling the truth". They're not claiming it was never indexed. You can try "build trust" all you like, but the harder you try, the more reasons will people find not to trust you.

Comment: There's "Not trusting", and then there's "being paranoid". Instead of jumping on everything that could've been worded differently, put things into perspective. This only affected a few people, and has already been resolved.

Comment: You are now arguing against statements I did not make, and so I do not defend them. (For example, I did not claim that they stated it was never indexed, or were not aware of this.) I only say that this is not what I regard "full transparency", and my impression from how this post is written is that the team does not take personal information and its accidental public exposure as seriously as would in my view be justified. To me, this means I will never use the developer stories, and have strong doubts about future services where personal data is involved. I might have tried them out otherwise!

Comment: There's always option 2: Don't provide that kind of personal data if you're not comfortable with it getting leaked _somewhere_, _anywhere_.

Comment: Yes, this attitude towards privacy is really a shame. I wrote an extensive complaint about this incident. On Facebook. Just kidding. They did the best they could, and I hardly know a site that I consider as trustworthy as stackoverflow. They *know* about their responsibility. And they have a name to lose. Of course, mistakes like this shouldn't happen, but they *do* happen, and I'm confident that this incident causes an even higher awareness among the people who are responsible for this community (i.e. something like this is unlikely to happen again soon or at all).

Comment: @Marco13: I'd like to agree, except I cannot. Although not documented in great detail, the measures taken to prevent this sort of leak in the future are based on developer trust alone. There is no infrastructure in place to enforce this, nor is it planned to implement one. Unless the system protects sensitive data, it will get leaked again. Maybe not due to a bug in the system, but rather a coordinated attack.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not an expert here, and not familiar with what *could* be set up as a technical infrastructure to prevent this. This **is** site where personal information (for Job negotiations) is part of the profile. Regardless of the tech infrastructure, there will **always** be developers responsible for the confidentiality. And for me, personally, there are reasons to assume that the people working for SO know their stuff, and take such things serious. And ... sorry, it may sound polemic, but *absolute* safety can only be achieved by never connecting your PC to the internet at all....

Comment: @Marco13: You seem to be confused, **which** information was leaked here. It wasn't information you see in the public profile. And this isn't about personal information either. It is about personally-identifiable information. If you need help imagining, how data can be secured: It can be encrypted, with the encryption key only being available to authorized parties. It could be stored in a location with restricted access. Nothing fancy, really, operating systems have been doing this literally for decades.

Comment: @IInspectable Again, I'm not an expert, and cannot argue here. As already mentioned above: As long as there has been "critical" data, there also have been "leaks". At some point, somebody *can* access the data, and if the responsible persons are not trustworthy, then no tech infrastructure will help. I think that the measures announced here will help to prevent information being leaked **accidentally**. Beyond that, everything relies on developer trust, as you also already said above. (From my side, there's no further need for discussion - no offense, I just can't say more about this)

Comment: @Marco13: See, that's precisely where we disagree. The proposed changes rely on developer trust alone. This does **not** prevent against accidentally leaking data. Tool- (or operating system-)enforced access control, on the other hand, would.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, this may have been a misunderstanding. You're right: It does not (technically) *prevent* a leak, but reduces the risk of an accidental leak by increasing the awareness. For the technical options, I can only give your points for granted, and hope that the SO team will undertake everything that is technically reasonably possible.

Comment: Developers make mistakes. It happens.

Comment: @DavidB: That's true, and completely undisputed. To me, it is important to see how the team reacts *when* this happens. For example, do I get (as in this case), 3 screens of contradicting information together with a conditional apology for an issue that does not bother me in the least? Or (as I would consider ideal), do I get a clear statement about everything that happened and could have happened together with an indication that the team is well aware of how sensitive the issue of personal information is, and truly sorry for having failed to live up to their high standards on one occasion?

Comment: I fully agree with this post. The phrase "for any inconvenience", or worse, "*if* any inconvenience", is terribly weaselly officialese that almost sounds like a backhanded inversion of what it should be. It almost sounds like it's *my* fault for feeling inconvenienced (*if* I should feel so!), and the apology is for *my reaction*, not for the causing incident. (It's similar to "I'm sorry you had to find out", or "I'm sorry you feel that way".) Don't worry about panicking me, my reaction is my choice. Please just talk straight to me.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not entirely sure *how* much effort or thought the PR departement puts into these wordings (I mean, whether they think *so* much more about this than any other sane person). When someone drops a cup of coffee and it spills over my lap, then I'd not argue about whether he apologizes for 1. spilling coffee over my lap or 2. not being able to hold a cup of coffee. As long as he doesn't try to convince me that "nothing happened" (something that is often seen in public "apologies"), I care less about his wording than about my lap. (Yes, the analogy may be far-fetched, but YKWIM)

Comment: I agree with this, if only because "inconvenience" sounds just about as fitting in this context as giving a seafood restaurant a bad rating because the owner's wife plays golf. It's the kind of canned wording that stands out so much as a non-sequitur that it hurts.

Comment: @Marco13: The analogy in relation to your example is: Someone spills a cup of coffee over your lap and then says "I'm sorry if anyone was inconvenienced in any way while I cleaned this up".