# Rollback edit which inlined very low quality image?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I just rolled an edit back on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598750/how-to-connect-to-a-database-table-in-java) ([screenshot of the question previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oudg1.png) and [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0to4W.png)). Another user previously inlined the image.
The image itself is a very low quality mashup of multiple screenshots taken with an actual camera instead of a screenshot tool:

[redacted on the off-chance that those passwords are real]

My goal of the rollback was to teach OP and maybe the initial editor a lesson that those types of images are not a good idea - pasting code and actual error messages are better.

Additionally I wrote a comment explaining my action:

> @GurV *[the user who did the initial edit]* those images are the reason new users are not allowed to post images - they should learn to post actual code, actual output and actual errors. Please do all of that OP, your images are to tiny, not sharp enough and please learn the shortcut to make screenshots if you fell like you have to do them

My questions now is: Was my rollback justified - or is there some other thing I should have done instead / in addition?

Comment: I probably would have just wrote a comment, as it was done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598750/how-to-connect-to-a-database-table-in-java#comment70400315_41598750), asking OP that he should posts the code and error message as plain text and would have explained that you can't copy the code out of an image easily and images are also not searchable.

Comment: @Rizier123 so you would have basically put more effort into explaining *why* the image is bad but leave the edit be? I wrote my comment first and only after looking at the image again decided to undo the edit because the quality of the image was just too bad.

Comment: That image is indeed low quality. Even worse, one of the windows it shows also has user credentials listed.

Comment: The edit doesn't improve the question, so I wouldn't have done it. But the comment explaining to OP why it is important to post the images as text brings the question further since OP then knows what he should do.

Comment: Not sure you can fix this kind of dumb.

Comment: @Will: At least the OP didn't use a gun to take those screenshots...

Comment: @Rizier123 It did improve the question.  The question is equally bad, but now uses fewer bytes to be bad.  The badness/byte has gone down, which is an improvement.

Comment: That's shockingly bad. Where's the wooden table??!

Comment: [related](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qBYi.jpg)

Comment: @Bryan If I had to guess those aren't *real* credentials at least. Then again, it might be the scarier truth that they *are* real

Comment: Not meaning to defend the images at all, but is there any chance the photo on the upper left is of a screen that doesn't have an easier way to get a screenshot (like a dumb terminal or ancient text-only PC)?

Comment: @JohnY That's irrelevant. If the poster can *see* the text to take a picture of it, and can type in the question box, they can type the text into the question box instead of posting a picture.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, agreed. Those do look like test creds. Though an OP lazy enough to post a question with an image this terrible might just be lazy enough to....... :)

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Who said anything about relevant? You appear to be too mission-oriented, friend. My comment was meant for a bit of levity, like Carpetsmoker's or honk's. Or Shog9's about the wooden table.

Comment: @Yakk - actually, if badness has stayed the same and byte has decreased, the badness/byte has gone **up**  ;)

Comment: No handdrawn red circles? Clearly one more reason to rollback!

Comment: Not sure why you brought it to meta after rolling back unless someone objected your rollback? would make some sense if you ask this before rolling back though.

Comment: @TJ because one other user questioned my action and I myself was not 100% sure my reaction was correct - I simply wanted confirmation or corrections in case it was wrong

Comment: FWIW, for questions like that, I have this canned comment in a userscript: `Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)`

Comment: A supposed programmer who takes pictures of his screen with a camera to ask for help. I just ... feel sorry for the users soon with leaked personal data once this guy gets to server-side programming. God help us when that happens.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your rollback was fine, and the comment to the editor was good. We have very good reasons for not allowing low-rep users to inline images, and people should not be "helpfully" inlining useless images like that.

Comment: I flat out refuse to inline images of text, and ask to copy and insert the code directly. (Sometimes with hilarious follow-ups: "so how do you copy text from a windows terminal" was one.) But there's always someone who does.

Comment: Thank you and all the commenters for the feedback :)

Comment: Hmm I might start doing this. Until now my policy has been "on-site is better than off-site" and then encourage the OP to take things further by replacing the image with better content. But this is a good point.