# What sorts of edits should editors make to posts, and why?

Tags: discussion, edits

Amongst the Stack Overflow community, we have some broadly understood ideas about what constitutes a good post. We think questions should contain a MCVE and answers should contain a clear solution. Posts should be reasonably well-spelled and formatted, and fluff should be kept to a minimum. Editors contribute to this effort by fixing up posts as much as they can, including the fixing of case, spelling, grammar, formatting, and so forth.

I thought it would be interesting for the community at large, and particularly for new posters, to understand how these themes are put into practice and shaped by editors over time. Moreover, different editors are likely to prioritise different errors, depending on their own stylistic bugbears - badly formatted code is anathema to some editors, but perhaps they don't mind txtspk or all-lower-case posting (and vice versa).

I will compile below a list of my own approach to editing, and would invite any other members who edit posts to do so as well. There is no single answer to this, but hopefully since this is Meta, that doesn't matter too much. Feedback on my edit approaches is very welcome from other editors, and other community members.

Comment: I don't understand why you think an exhaustive list of "things that can be edited" would be useful, much less maintainable. Isn't it obvious that edits are meant to fix *anything that can be improved* about a post, and that that intentionally covers a wide (potentially unlimited) range of things?

Comment: @Cody: I think my answer tries to cover that objection. In my experience as an editor, there are not many categories of improvement, and if we can categorise them, maybe there is value in explaining these thought processes to new users? My themes below are quite broad, so are there kinds of edit that I have not covered?

Comment: FWIW I don't believe that the below will need much maintenance, and if somehow users were to adhere to my fairly stringest presentational preferences, we would barely need to do any editing at all `:-)`.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How do I make a good edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I list below some of the approaches I take when editing. I note here that editing is my way of giving back to a very helpful community, just in the same way that people spend time crafting good questions or answers. I think there is value in improving posts, both for the edification of the poster, and for the benefit of future readers.

For some of my edit themes, I see errors in that category so often I have a bookmark to check to see if any clear-up would be helpful.

Whilst the below list covers a number of different posting errors, I endorse the *Meta* view that if a post is edited, it should be edited for *all* obvious issues, rather than just one. This keeps front-page changes and review queue pings to a minimum, whilst making changes that editors deem to be necessary.

I also note that whilst I am happy to do some editing, I would discourage posters from the assumption that the editor community is their spell-checker and auto-correct. Downvotes on posts that are obviously lazy are encouraged for this reason, and where posters are clearly ignoring edits made to their earlier material.

### Code, logs and console I/O formatting

Code formatting often needs repairing, because:

- It was just posted into the answer box without indentation, and so only the naturally indented parts of the material appear to the confused user
- HTML or XML has not been indented, which creates a mess (or disappears entirely) without inline or block indentation

In this category I am usually inclined to downvote, since there are not many excuses for not using the preview window.

### Txtspk

I have noticed there is a reasonable correlation between posters who are too lazy to type real words and the amount of effort that goes into a post. Words like the following should be expanded into real words (not an exhaustive list!):

- plz/pls (please)
- thx (thanks)
- shud (should)
- tq (thank you)
- u, ur (you/your)
- sth (something)

If there are more than a couple of them, I will downvote and make a note in the edit message:

> Expand txtspk (-1)

I do try to be forgiving of people whose first language is not English, but I also take the view that txtspk is a deliberate manglement that harms ease of reading.

### Spelling

If there are just one or two spelling errors, I will fix them without penalty, especially if it is clear that the poster does not have English as a first language. However if there are many, I am sometimes inclined to downvote, especially if my browser's built-in spelling checker makes it easy (can't people use a spelling checker before they submit?).

I notice that apostrophe constructions often need fixing, and either the apostrophe is simply missed off, or is replaced by a space (do some keyboards not have easily accessible apostrophes, perhaps?):

- didnt, cant, wasnt, couldnt (should be didn't, can't, wasn't, couldn't)
- Im (I'm)
- i m (I'm)

### Begging

We get several questions a day featuring requests for "urgent" or "ASAP" treatment, and since I [posted this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) I think the number of overly demanding posts has dwindled considerably. These days it is unusual for me not to downvote in this category.

I categorise begging to also include the following phrases:

- Please help
- Please help me
- Please help me out
- Please help me out here
- I am new to {technology}, so please help me (and all variations thereof)
- All of the above, but with 'plz'
- This is very important for me
- Deadlines of any kind
- That the user is "tearing their hair out" or is "desperate"
- Eagerly awaiting your answers/assistance/replies
- Sad/crying emoticons intended to elicit sympathy

I note that posters who add begging phrases often also follow a standard boilerplate, and if we could discourage it, the amount of fluff-editing necessary would drop dramatically. The boilerplate follows a highly predictable pattern:

> Hi! I have a problem. This is my first post on stackoverflow.
>
> {incomplete problem explanation, often with no attempt shown or evidence of research}
>
> I have been stuck on this for {time}. I am new to {technology}, so please help me out. I have googled the whole internet and looked at all posts on Stack Overflow and nothing fits my issue. Plz help! It will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

It is also worth discouraging pleading because it may contribute to readers skipping the question. As well as being redundant, there is something irritating and ingratiating about [please help me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+help+me%22+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion), and it would certainly be interesting to see if there is a statistically significant increase in downvotes or zero-answers as a result of this fluff.

I note too that posters given to this approach will often add it as a boilerplate suffix to their comments too:

> @halfer I did not get wot u meant. Plz help me

### Meta commentary

Posts should, in my view, not contain commentary about any meta-aspect of the site. If you received a downvote, don't edit the post to ask why. You may add a comment if you wish, though I'd say there is not much point, since if a downvoter wished to remain anonymous, they will have long gone, and will not be returning in order to respond to disgruntled remarks.

My primary justification here is that the numbers of users who log in or vote is rather small in comparison to the number of readers, and so any squabbles about voting are not of interest to most readers.

In this category I include any meta-commentary intended to head off downvotes before they have happened:

> Please don't downvote/down vote

I also trim out vote-begging:

> If this answer was useful, please accept and upvote, thanks!

### Salutations

Most of these will appear in questions, but sometimes answers contain them, since they are (incorrectly) addressed to one person:

- Hi/Hy
- Ladies and gentlemen
- Guys/guyz
- Gentlemen/Gents
- Dear experts
- Hello Stack Overflow community
- Thanks dude/bro

These are fluff and can be removed.

### Case and punctuation

The readability of a post is substantially improved if standard guidelines covering case and punctuation are followed. I tend to look for:

- Sentences and titles start with a capital letter (even if the poster is using a mobile device to post)
- We prefer titles in sentence case here, rather than title case (style guides tend to find title case too formal these days anyway)
- Proper nouns, including brand names, such as Facebook
- Proper nouns that prefer camel case, such as WordPress, JavaScript and MySQL
- The personal pronoun 'I'
- Acronyms should be all upper, such as PHP and SQL
- Commas and full stops should have zero preceding spaces and one following space
- Parentheses should have one outer preceding space, and no spaces immediately on the inside (like this). They should also be round and not square or brace.

### Unnecessary apologies

Often new posters will start by launching into a lot of boilerplate apology, and it is not necessary. This includes:

- I am new here
- Sorry for any mistakes or not following the rules
- Please let me know if you need to see anything else
- Sorry for my English

All of that can be trimmed, though since this is not an egregious error, I won't downvote as a result.

### Answer fluff

I don't search for these as much, since good answers are not spoiled by them. However, if I am editing an answer anyway, these will usually be zapped:

- Happy coding!
- Hope that helps!

### Stylistic misspellings

I see quite a lot of these too:

- Or should that be alot? ("a lot" is two words - an "alot" [is a mythical creature](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html))
- Here is teh best answer (a common typo of "the" has become an internet meme)

### Religious material

Unfortunately we have a small number of readers who believe that the Stack Exchange network is a suitable place for religious proselytisation, and that any edits to reduce this fluff is an abridgement of their freedom of thought. I have explained to a couple of persistent offenders that edits of this kind made by the community are merely to keep posts on topic, and that they are entirely free to post religious material elsewhere on the internet. As I understand it, the community and moderators are broadly very tolerant of religious themes in profiles and avatars also.

- Allah
- Thanks to {deity} I solve it
- God bless
- Jesus loves you
- I've been told not to add this here but Jesus literally saved my life and {goes on for 94 pages}

### Title tagging and other title problems

Often home-made tags will appear in questions, and I try to iron these out. More information [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often).

Where a title includes the meta-tag [Solved] I will often roll this back and move any answer to a community-wiki answer. However this is a lot of edit work, given the rate that [new ones are added](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3asolved), so sometimes I will ask the OP in each case to do it.

If I am editing a post anyway and I find that a title is too chatty or insufficiently detailed, I will sometimes rewrite it to encapsulate the problem. Extremely poor titles that consist only of fluff, such as the following, merit a downvote:

> Please help me with my code problem

Comment: Change **Title tags** to a more broad "Title porblem"? As long as I am editing other stuff, I try to change "Code gives error" to something more useful as well.

Comment: **Inline images** only when they are [actually useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341336/rollback-edit-which-inlined-very-low-quality-image) - and comment when it is not.

Comment: **Do not edit code** because you may be destroying the actual question. Particularly for languages such as Python, where indentation matters. I've seen a couple of such "helpful edits" that made the porblem magically disappear. ("Do not" ~ "unless you *really really* know what you are doing".)

Comment: Good try. But 1,555 words. 12 headings. 51 bullet points (yes, I counted).Am I really expected to read this complete "answer" in meta? Or should I simply down-vote because, well, most anyone shouldn't be expected to wade through this? Now that I'm done editorializing, I'll add my true thought on editing separately....

Comment: EDITS. We all know when to do them. But do we know when not to? Religion - obviously. Or is it? Why edit when you can simply mark for deletion? Title tagging - YES, please! Begging, salutations, unnecessary apologies, misspellings - WHY? Let it go, it's not worth 1,555 words for me (or anyone doing a search) to care about. In fact, it's not word changing 15.55 words if I get the meaning, right? Answer fluff. Um, this (self) answer is the epitome of that IMHO.

Comment: @SurajJain: that has been covered very well elsewhere. "Readers may vote anonymously for any reason they like as long as they do not deliberately target one user". That said, I do often add `(-1)` explanatory remarks to edit messages, and less often, but still reasonably frequently, a comment under a post (this takes up more time, but can be useful).

Comment: @halfer: Too much examples. The examples are too specific. Txtspk should be edited out, period. A list of examples can lead to occurrences not being mentioned -> ignored.

Comment: If this is a guide, make it (Question & Answer) a community wiki, and de-personalize it. (Don't say "I am inclined to..."). Remove all opinions, only leave facts.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'd be willing to put more effort into this if the community believes it has value, but it may not be a good use of my time if it is considered "too broad" anyway. I see what you mean about opinion versus fact - I was somewhat taking the view that this was a good place to see if they are facts that suit most editors (especially since editing is quite a subjective art).

Comment: "Too broad" aside, it's also a duplicate ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: yep, I'd run with that. That said, the primary closure as too broad gives me pause, since some well-established users here do not think it is useful (upvotes notwithstanding). Given that it took a lot of effort to compile, there may not be much value in moving  it (plus your style feedback) to the other post. I will see if I can summon the necessary enthusiasm in the future `:-)`.