# Should I roll back edits that inline images of code?

Tags: discussion, edits, images, rollbacks

I saw this question [Rollback edit which inlined very low quality image?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341336/rollback-edit-which-inlined-very-low-quality-image) Here is a quote:

> The image itself is a very low quality mashup of multiple screenshots taken with an actual camera instead of a screenshot tool

I wonder if this also can be applicable to any edits where someone inlines an image of code.

The questioner in the above question motivates the rollback with

> My goal of the rollback was to teach OP and maybe the initial editor a lesson that those types of images are not a good idea

The accepted answer (with 30/-2 votes) says:

> Your rollback was fine, and the comment to the editor was good. We have very good reasons for not allowing low-rep users to inline images, and people should not be "helpfully" inlining useless images like that.

To me it seems pretty fair to also apply the above reasoning on images of code, irregardless of the image quality. Am I right?

So my question is simply this: Is it correct to rollback such edits?

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate of the question I linked. Neither the question nor the answer mentions images of code at all, and it is far from obvious that the answer to both is the same.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Only thing I would say is, moderators (and post owners) have the ability to retroactively *reject* a suggested edit, as long as there have been no intervening edits. The difference between rejecting a suggested edit and simply rolling it back is that the suggester doesn't get to keep the +2 rep from having the edit approved when it is rejected. So, in these cases, it'd be nice to ask a moderator to reject the edit, instead of simply rolling it back.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not a dup. It's only a dup for those who KNOW that it is the same, but neither the question nor the answer mentions images of code. It would be great if you reopened this and posted that comment as an answer.

Comment: *“It's only a dup for those who KNOW that it is the same…”* Yes, and I know it’s the same. That’s why I voted to indicate it is the same. Duplicate doesn’t necessarily imply *you* should have known, especially not on Meta. It just means “these two questions have the same answer(s)”.

Comment: @CodyGray I must say I find that a bit strange and confusing. Just to take it to the extreme. There exists questions here where the answer is a simple "yes". It would be quite strange to make all questions where the answer is a "yes" to a duplicate.

Furthermore, if I would have found this question while searching I would probably have assumed that it was wrongfully closed as a dup and I would not trust the other answer to be valid for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yea, images of code should be *replaced* with actual code. (Preferably by the OP)

They shouldn't be inlined. So sure, roll them back, as the edit didn't improve the quality of the post.