# Where did SO get my old phone number from?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, personal-data

I've never looked into the Jobs or the Developer Story aspect of the site properly, so, today, I was taking a look around and I found that SO had an *old* number of mine stored. The issue here is that I don't actually remember *ever* adding a phone number?

[image]

(now removed)

So, if I didn't add this number (if memory serves right), then where did this number come from?

Is there any way to audit the history of the developer story to see when changes were made?

<sup>The reason why I doubt that I added my number is because of the reason that I tend to be careful about where and what details I release of mine, especially things like phone numbers. It could be that I added it myself and forgot but I just want to confirm.</sup>

Comment: Unless something changed since November 2016, you have added the phone number yourself. ["it's not like we got the phone number from anyone else or from anywhere else. But to be specific, the number was on their CV in Careers. – Taryn♦ Nov 28 '16"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338573/sensitive-info-disclosure#comment415765_338583)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not (yet) psychic. If there was a number there, then you supplied it yourself at some point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure, that's why I wrote that I may have forgotten that I added it but it *could* also be possible they now employ some other means to get this data.

Comment: Did you sign in with Facebook? It might have gotten it from there?

Comment: Could that possibly be coming from Google SSO? Mine's filled too, but I have a bad memory when it comes to what I filled on which site/job board/you name it

Comment: @samm82 nope. I don't have a Facebook account.

Comment: @b.enoit.be I've only ever signed in via an SO account, never through any third party.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO works like this, but some job search sites import information from a resume or CV when you upload such a file.  Is it possible that you previously uploaded a document with the phone number?

Comment: @Steve-o169 I don't believe I have ever uploaded a CV, personal statement, or any other jobs document as I've never looked for a job through SO. Though yes, I have come across that feature with other sites.

Comment: Did you ever use the old SO mobile app, or the general SE app?

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"Stack Overflow is not (yet) psychic"*, when can we expect to see that update?

Comment: @LogicalBranch in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Comment: It's not about being psychic, it's about connecting data from 3rd parties.

Comment: Maybe you had your phone set in some other website and the browser recorded it. So when you were filling out your developer profile here in SO it automatically filled it out for you and you didn't realise?

Comment: @ThalesMinussi If I was a betting man, I'd put my money on that as the (potential) cause. The only issue is I don't remember going on that page except when I noticed this issue ~2 days ago.

Comment: Sounds like browser autofill

Comment: [coding drunk](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/ballmer_peak.png)?  (There's a [handbook](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CWQ3U5vWoAAgjuR.jpg) for that.)

Comment: Did your company happen to sign up for Teams?

Comment: @TimPost nope, not to my knowledge.

Comment: Alright, well, that rules that out then. I'll write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 12):

I ran down the list of possibilities on how this *could* have happened, even taking into consideration possible glitches on our side. Long story short, you *almost certainly* provided it without noticing, possibly through autofill?

I looked at a possible edge case of what happens when users in an organization are invited to join a team when a company signs up and provides their details (this is the only other place to my knowledge where we even give an ability to enter a phone number) but that doesn't make sense either, because if it were a bug where we grabbed the wrong field, it would be a *company* phone number.

While you don't remember it, I'm *very certain* you must have inadvertently given it. If you want to keep digging here we're happy to help, but we'd need to take this private (so the contact form and providing a link to this post would be your best bet).

Sorry that I didn't find anything 100% absolute, but I did 100% absolutely rule out anything else other than you submitting it, as far as I can tell. I'm pinging a few other folks closer to the jobs stuff just to be sure; if anything else turns up, they'll write an answer too.

Comment: '*I'm pinging a few other folks closer to the jobs stuff just to be sure; if anything else turns up, they'll write an answer too.*' - Thanks Tim. As an aside, I just want to say that this sort of support is what makes SE / SO different to other sites. Much appreciated. I'm going to hold off from accepting just in case the other folks dig anything worthwhile up.