# Are recruiters able to directly download my CV from jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I just got spammed by a recruiter (LinkedIn request, phone call, and WhatsApp message). I missed the call but listened to the voicemail - "I got your CV from Stack Overflow".

I feel like I did upload a CV in the past to Stack Overflow jobs (but I can't find it now). So my question is two-fold:

- Is there a way to upload/see uploaded CVs so I can see what information is up there?
- If yes to the first, is there a way recruiters can get to this without using the built in Stack Overflow jobs communication mechanism?

Essentially this was a cold call and if my information was found on Stack Overflow I'm surprised I didn't receive a message in my inbox. Obviously until I can confirm the first point (my CV is the only place my phone number would be listed) it's unclear if she really did find me on here.

---

I've managed to answer the first part myself. Within *"Edit Profile & Settings"* there is a *"Job Preferences"* section which contains my CV. That does have my current phone number on, so I guess the recruiter got hold of this, without having to send me a message first on SO?

[image: Screenshot from Jobs as described above]

Comment: You assume a recruiter told you the truth?

Comment: @HansPassant no, not at all! That's why point 1 I was trying to verify if my details  (phone number) even exist on StackOverflow :)

Comment: @Ian Similar (based on your comment): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382249/where-did-so-get-my-old-phone-number-from

Comment: @Script47 thanks. I've been unable to find a phone number (or even a place to add it in) within the developer story so far.